# XSD Types to Regular Expression

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, types, xsd

Is there a simple way to find the Regular Expressions for the default XSD Types like:

- `xsd:NMTOKEN`
- `xsd:NMTOKENS`
- `xsd:gYear`

All i found is [this Page](http://www.xmlplease.com/xmlname), that contains the Regular Expression for `NMTOKEN` and `NMTOKENS`. But i need more Types like `gYear` and `string`.

Hope you can help me. 
Thanks!

Comment: We probably can help you, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, the document you have found links to the official spec of the W3C schema datatypes https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes which defines https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#gYear for instance. I am not sure what you understand "the regular expression" of a datatype to be and why you need that, if you use a validating XML parser then it validates your data based on the schema spec, you don't have to write any regular expressions to use schemas and their datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

The lexical space of each type defined by XSD is given by the XSD specification.  In XSD 1.0, the information is sometimes given informally and is not discussed when it seemed obvious; in [XSD 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/), it is given explicitly for all types.  XSD 1.1 uses an extended BNF grammar for this information, but there should be no problem translating it into regular expressions.

Note that for types with the whitespace facet set to replace or collapse you will need to decide whether you wish to perform the appropriate whitespace processing or require that your input already have the whitespace simplified or collapsed.

Answer (score -1):

Without any info on what you've tried so far I expect that you aren't too sure how regex works...

```
xsd:gYear
```

will match `xsd:gYear` exactly.

```
xsd:(\w+)
```

will extract whatever word (`a-Z` or `0-9` or `_`) is written directly after `xsd:`.

```
xsd:(NMTOKENS?|gYear|string)
```

will match on any of the types `NMTOKEN`, `NMTOKENS`, `gYear`, or `string` and capture the type.

Please update your question with more info on [what you've tried and what you are trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I need the RegEx because i have to validate the values before they are in the XML - The Problem is that i only have an XSD, and i want to generate the validation by help of the XSD Types. So i need a table with the XSD Types and the RegEx.